# How can I drop database column via ssh

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3

I need to uninstall one of the modules.

I need to drop the column from the database

How can I run this command via ssh to remove it?

I tried on this way not working with me.

1- sudo mysql -u root -p

2- DELETE FROM setup_module WHERE module='_'

Answer (score 0):

Please **Delete** module from your directory

app/code/**Your/Module/**

and run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Your module's entry will be removed automatically

cheers!!!

Comment: I did but I need to reinstall the module because I installed it on the wrong directory on the first time. when I reinstall it again I get the same error

Comment: first do step as I mentioned then try to install again on proper direcory

Comment: I get the same error ?? which error??

Comment: MT Email 2 exception(s): Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'is_mt_email' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `email_template` AS `main_table` WHERE (`is_mt_email` = '1') Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'is_mt_email' in 'where clause' Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'is_mt_email' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `email_template` AS `main_table` WHERE (`is_mt_email` = '1') <pre> ...

Comment: even If I delete module from the directory
It still exists on app/etc/config.php and database

Comment: even If I delete module from the directory It still exists on app/etc/config.php and database – 
*after that you need to run command as I mentioned in my answer*

Comment: is_mt_email ?? If your custom table is also created then also delete that table too..and reinstall module

Comment: even If I delete module from the directory It still exists on app/etc/config.php and database – after that you need to run command as I mentioned in my answer ---> I did

Do you know how to run this command
DELETE FROM setup_module WHERE module='<Vendor>_<Module>'

Comment: ``mysql -u root -p`` then enter your password of database user. then type ``use your_database`` then run your delete query

Answer (score 0):

Please visit the dev docs link

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall-mods.html

if you installed the extension via composer you have to execute:

```
php bin/magento module:uninstall Vendor_Module
```

if your extension is placed under the app/code directory then you have to remove the extension from your server using the below command

```
rm -rf app/code/Vendor/Module
```

and execute upgrade command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Thanks!!